# Apple Application Loader error - Unable to find an iTunes Connect user

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, application-loader

I'm encountering a very unusual error when attempting to submit my iOS app for app store review.

When uploading via Application Loader, it stops with the reason:

> Unable to find an iTunes Connect user for username 110143776. This
>   username may not be enabled for iTunes Connect. Contact your team
>   admin for assistance.

I have been successfully using this account for over a year (note: the user ID in the above quote is edited to protect my real id). I have double checked my iTunes Connect role and confirmed my role as Admin. I have just the other day successfully submitted an update to a separate app.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to make sure that your account is selected for admin and technical into itunes connect.
Please signout your itunes account. restart your internet connection and restart your system. And again try to upload build via Xcode or itunes. It should work for you.